# data transformation from pandas to json

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`:

```py
d = {'col1': [1, 2,0,55,12,3], 'col3': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df 

    col1        col3
0   1           A
1   2           A
2   0           A
3   55          B
4   12          B
6   3           B
```

and want to build a *Json* from it, as the results looks like this :

```
json_result = { 'A' : [1,2,0], 'B': [55,12,3] }
```

basically, I would like for each group of the *col3* to affect an array of its corresponding values from the dataframe

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you. As is, you show no attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate list and then use [`Series.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
print (df.groupby('col3')['col1'].agg(list).to_json())
{"A":[1,2,0],"B":[55,12,3]}
```

or if need dictionary use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
print (df.groupby('col3')['col1'].agg(list).to_dict())
{'A': [1, 2, 0], 'B': [55, 12, 3]}
```